# Debian MySQL extremly slow and very high number o SELECTs

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a Debian Server with Apache running. Since yesterday I have problems with MySQL performance. I have four apps running. Wordpress, phpMyAdmin and two own ones. Since yesterday Wordpress, phpMyAdmin and one of the own ones are terribly slow. So slow that the browser often stops with a timeout. All static pages without DB work at normal speed. So I guessed that it has to do with MySQL. I checked everything I know but can't find anything odd. Also I have one app running that also uses (select and insert) the DB and this app wors good.

What can I do to solve this? What aditional info do you need? Where can I start looking for the problem?

[image]

I enabled slow query log and opened one of the slow pages but the log stys empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find from where the running Selects come from execute SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G and check the Host field.
Additionally to log all selects enable the general query log for few minutes and check source_host field.

Comment: In the process list in phpMyAdmin is only Localhost. Can I be sure that this list is complete?

I restarted the server so all scripts should have stopped. But the number of SELECTs is too high.

Comment: It is complete. So they come from an application that runs on the same box.  what kind of statements are running? are all the same? Are you sure you don't missing any index?

Comment: I updated my question. Please let me know which other screenshots / info could help to solve this.

Comment: Please find attached.

Comment: I don't see any running statements, you better enable the general query log for 1-2 mins and share the output